# Flink - SQL Tumble End on event time not returning any result

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Flink job that consumes from a kafka topic and tries to create windows based on few columns like eventId and eventName. Kafka topic has `eventTimestamp` as the timestamp field with timestamp populated in millis

```
DataStreamSource kafkaStream = env.fromSource(
    kafkaSource, //kafkaSource is the KafkaSource builder
    WatermarkStrategy.forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(20)), "KafkaSource");

// Doing some transformations to map to POJO class.

Table kafkaTable = tableEnv.fromDataStream(
    kafkaSource,
    Schema.newBuilder()
        .columnByExpression("proc_time", "PROCTIME()")
        // eventTimestamp is in millis
        .columnByExpression("event_time", "TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ(eventTimestamp, 3)")
        .watermark("event_time", "event_time - INTERVAL '20' SECOND")
        .build();
```

The `Tumble_End` window query returns rows when `proc_time` is used, but doesn't return anything when I use `event_time`.

```
SELECT TUMBLE_END(event_time, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE), COUNT(DISTINCT eventId)
FROM kafkaTable GROUP BY TUMBLE(event_time, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE)"

-- This query gives some results
SELECT TUMBLE_END(proc_time, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE), COUNT(DISTINCT eventId)
FROM kafkaTable GROUP BY TUMBLE(proc_time, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE)"
```

I tried to set `env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);` but this is deprecated as I'm using `1.14.4` stable version.

I tried adding custom WatermarkStrategy as well, but nothing worked. I'm not able to identify this behaviour. Can someone help on this?

David - Here is the code I'm using.

```
main() {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()
    val tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)

    val kafkaSource = KafkaSource.builder<String>()
        .setBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")
        .setTopics("an-topic")
        .setGroupId("testGroup")
        .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
        .setValueOnlyDeserializer(SimpleStringSchema())
        .build()

    val kafkaStream = env.fromSource(kafkaSource,
        WatermarkStrategy.forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(20)), "KafkaSource")

    val kafkaRowMapper = kafkaStream.map(RowMapper())

    val finalTable = tableEnv.fromDataStream(kafkaRowMapper,
        Schema.newBuilder()
            .columnByExpression("proc_time", "PROCTIME()")
            .columnByExpression("event_time", "TO_TIMESTAMP_LTZ(f2, 3)")
            .watermark("event_time", "event_time - INTERVAL '20' SECOND")
            .build()
    ).renameColumns(
        `$`("f0").`as`("eventId"),
        `$`("f1").`as`("eventName"),
        `$`("f3").`as`("eventValue")
    )
    tableEnv.createTemporaryView("finalTable", finalTable)

    val sqlQuery = "SELECT eventId, eventName, TUMBLE_END(event_time, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE) AS event_time_new, " +
            "LAST_VALUE(eventValue) AS eventValue FROM finalTable " +
            "GROUP BY eventId, eventName, TUMBLE(event_time, INTERVAL '1' MINUTE)"
    val resultTable = tableEnv.sqlQuery(sqlQuery)
    tableEnv.toDataStream(resultTable).print()

    env.execute("TestJob")

}

class RowMapper: MapFunction<String, Tuple4<String, String, Long, Float>> {
    override fun map(value: String): Tuple4<String, String, Long, Float> {
        val lineArray = value.split(",")

        return Tuple4 (lineArray[0], lineArray[1], lineArray[2].toLong(), lineArray[3].toFloat())
    }
}
```

Kafka topic has values like this

```
event1,Util1,1647614467000,0.12
event1,Util1,1647614527000,0.26
event1,Util1,1647614587000,0.71
event2,Util2,1647614647000,0.08
event2,Util2,1647614707000,0.32
event2,Util2,1647614767000,0.23
event2,Util2,1647614827000,0.85
event1,Util1,1647614887000,0.08
event1,Util1,1647614947000,0.32
```

Comment: How are you doing the testing? A likely explanation is that you haven't provided enough data to trigger the window(s).

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson - Thanks for your response. I have populated the kafka topic with some 3 month's old data and running the job. Does the kafka topic need to be published every time? I am using earliest offset in the properties.

Comment: Hi @DavidAnderson, I've also added the code I'm using for this and kafka input. Can you please check and let know what else I have to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the below line after creating table environment and then I'm able to create windows using event_time

```
tableEnv.config.configuration.setString("table.exec.source.idle-timeout", "5000 ms")
```

Comment: I added the configure and it works. But have no idea why the property affect the behavior... you have any idea?


btw, the code snippet in Python: `table_env.get_config().set("table.exec.source.idle-timeout", "5000 ms")`

Comment: As I observed, there is a slight delay while consuming from the topic. During this, source remains idle so to avoid that, set the timeout.